# Slice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slice

I'm embarked on a JavaScript journey, and have the following code which I really need to understand in details. Especially the line where it says `if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ")`

```
    var str = prompt("Enter some text");
var numChars = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
    if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ") {
        alert("No double spaces!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice  In the `if` it should probably be `"  "` (two spaces).

Comment: That code seems wrong

Comment: indexOf or regex would suit this problem better

Comment: Thats true. It should be double spaces. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing with a single space.

```
if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ") {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                          ^^^ single space
```

The comparison is only `true` in one case, at the end of the string with a single space. All other comparisons evaluates to `false`, because a string with the length of two is never equal to a string with a single character.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that, for each letter `i` in the entered text, to the letter `i + 2`, if they are equal to `"  "`, then they are two spaces.

In other words, it is checking each of the two letter combinations in the text to see if they match two spaces

For example:

`"En", "nt", "te", "er", "r ", " s", "so", "om"` etc...

So, slice is 'slicing' letters in the range specified in the parameters: `str.slice(beginIndex[, endIndex])`

**Edit:** Didn't see the prompt() call, so updated accordingly.

Perhaps try this in order to get a better idea of what's happening:

```
var str = prompt("Enter some text");
var numChars = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
    if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ") {
        alert("No double spaces!");
        break;
    } else {
        document.write(str.slice(i, i + 2) + "<br>")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`str.slice(i, i + 2)` inside a `for` loop will parse the string `str` taking two consecutive characters at a time with indices `i` and `i+1` where `i` will have all values from `0` to `length` of `str` according to the `for` loop.

**Note** : In your code snippet by this `if(str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ")` you are comparing two characters with single character which is white space. So it can never be true.

Have a look at a better example for more clear understanding.

```js
var str1 = "Single space";
var str2 = "Double  space";

var numChars1 = str1.length;
var numChars2 = str2.length;

// Check is str1 has double spaces
for (var i = 0; i < numChars1; i++) {
  if (str1.slice(i, i + 2) === "  ") {
    console.log("Double spaces found in str1");
    break;
  }
}

// Check is str2 has double spaces
for (var i = 0; i < numChars1; i++) {
  if (str2.slice(i, i + 2) === "  ") {
    console.log("Double spaces found in str2");
    break;
  }
}
```

Learn and find more example about slice on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Comment: Thanks for great help :)